# Django slow query performance improve

Tags: sql, django, performance, postgresql

I'm using Django with Postgres and have the following tables:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    description = models.ManyToManyField('descriptions.Description', through='DescriptionPersonUser')

class DescriptionPersonUser(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    description = models.ForeignKey('descriptions.Description')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        unique_together = ('person', 'description', 'user')

class Description(models.Model):
    description_id=models.AutoField (primary_key=True)
    description_word=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)

class AuthUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
   ...
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
```

The Person table has more than 1.5 mio rows and other tables have no more than 100 rows each. As I understand this should still be reasonable to perform queries that perform "normally". I want to order the Person table by count annotating count from the DescriptionPersonUser table.

```
person_list = Person.objects.annotate(count=Count('descriptionpersonuser')).order_by('-count')[:10]
```

this query took cca 50000 ms to load. Than I tried to execute it in raw sql and improved a lot to cca 1900 ms.

```
person_list= Person.objects.raw('SELECT "person"."person_id", COUNT("persons_descriptionpersonuser"."id") AS "count" FROM "person" LEFT OUTER JOIN "persons_descriptionpersonuser" ON ( "person"."person_id" = "persons_descriptionspersonuser"."person_id" ) GROUP BY "person"."person_id" ORDER BY "count" DESC, "person"."person_id" ASC LIMIT 10'),
```

I also created the index on persons_descriptionpersonuser:

```
CREATE INDEX index_descriptionpersonuser ON persons_descriptionpersonuser (person_id, description_id, id);
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there still margin to speed up the query? Or is 1900 ms for 1+ mio rows query decent?
2. Since I don't see any difference in query speed with the created index, how can I check if the index is working or if is influencing the query?

edited (as per [Tomasz Jakub Rup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5493302/tomasz-jakub-rup) suggestion adding EXPLAIN ANALYZE results):

without index_descriptionpersonuser:

```
Limit  (cost=138185.30..138185.33 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=2470.974..2470.976 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=138185.30..142177.82 rows=1597006 width=8) (actual time=2470.973..2470.975 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (count(persons_descriptionpersonuser.id)), person.person_id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..103674.58 rows=1597006 width=8) (actual time=0.402..1945.107 rows=1597006 loops=1)
               Group Key: person.person_id
               ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.56..79719.49 rows=1597006 width=8) (actual time=0.378..1014.179 rows=1597016 loops=1)
                     Merge Cond: (person.person_id = persons_descriptionpersonuse.person_id)
                     ->  Index Only Scan using person_pkey on person  (cost=0.43..75718.86 rows=1597006 width=4) (actual time=0.359..610.272 rows=1597006 loops=1)
                           Heap Fetches: 235898
                     ->  Index Scan using persons_descriptionpersonuse_person_id on persons_descriptionpersonuser  (cost=0.14..12.42 rows=19 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.025 rows=20 loops=1)
 Planning time: 17.879 ms
 Execution time: 2472.821 ms
(13 rows)
```

with index_descriptionpersonuser:

```
Limit  (cost=138185.55..138185.58 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=2341.349..2341.352 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=138185.55..142178.07 rows=1597006 width=8) (actual time=2341.325..2341.325 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (count(persons_descriptionpersonuser.id)), person.person_id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..103674.83 rows=1597006 width=8) (actual time=0.106..1819.330 rows=1597006 loops=1)
               Group Key: person.person_id
               ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.56..79719.74 rows=1597006 width=8) (actual time=0.092..877.874 rows=1597016 loops=1)
                     Merge Cond: (person.person_id = persons_descriptionpersonuser.person_id)
                     ->  Index Only Scan using person_pkey on person  (cost=0.43..75718.86 rows=1597006 width=4) (actual time=0.023..473.046 rows=1597006 loops=1)
                           Heap Fetches: 235898
                     ->  Index Only Scan using index_descriptionpersonuser on persons_descriptionpersonuser  (cost=0.14..12.44 rows=20 width=8) (actual time=0.059..0.085 rows=20 loops=1)
                           Heap Fetches: 20
 Planning time: 0.715 ms
 Execution time: 2343.815 ms
(14 rows)
```

as [Tomasz Jakub Rup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5493302/tomasz-jakub-rup) suggested the optimised sql query now takes cca 40 ms. Here are the results:

```
Limit  (cost=1.50..1.52 rows=8 width=8) (actual time=0.061..0.064 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1.50..1.52 rows=8 width=8) (actual time=0.060..0.061 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (count(id)), person_id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1.30..1.38 rows=8 width=8) (actual time=0.039..0.044 rows=10 loops=1)
               Group Key: person_id
               ->  Seq Scan on persons_descriptionpersonuser  (cost=0.00..1.20 rows=20 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.018 rows=20 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.175 ms
 Execution time: 0.129 ms
(9 rows)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Your second question:

Look at result of

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "person"."person_...
```

query. If You find the `index_descriptionpersonuser` in result the yes, Your query use index. If no, try to create other index. Maybe on `person_id` only?

First question: Yes, this query can be faster. Show result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE...` then we try to speed-up the query.

**Note**

Raw query is probably faster because they get data from PostgreSQL cache.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. I added the EXPLAIN ANALYZE results with and without the index.. there is a minimal difference

Comment: Try `SELECT "persons_descriptionpersonuser"."person_id", COUNT("persons_descriptionpersonuser"."id") AS "count" FROM "persons_descriptionpersonuser" GROUP BY "persons_descriptionpersonuser"."person_id" ORDER BY "count" DESC, "persons_descriptionpersonuser"."person_id" ASC LIMIT 10` and of course `EXPLAIN ANALYZE....`

Comment: wow awesome.. with your query now loading is reduced to less than 40ms ..thanks this was very helpful..